# PHP chmod permission denied

Tags: php, chmod, permission-denied, unlink

I am using mac and try to unlink a file via PHP:

```
$old_path = 'tmp/table.csv';
if(file_exists($old_path)){
   chmod($old_path, 777);
   unlink($old_path);
}
```

It looks like chmod is permission denied. I searched online but get no ideas. Someone says chown, how does it work?

Comment: http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chown.html

Comment: I don't know exactly for macs but I can tell for linux that chmod requires root permissions. Make sure that you're running server by user with sufficient permissions.

Comment: @maremp You're incorrect; `chmod` can be executed by the owner of the file.

Comment: That's correct but if OP is getting permission denied, they'll obviously need a account with greater permissions.

Answer (score 5):

The user executing the command has no rights to execute the chmod command.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your server is in the group associated with the files. Usually its www-data or www or something similar

https://serverfault.com/questions/272551/how-do-you-give-execute-permissions-to-apache2-user-and-not-to-everyone-else

Comment: Oh, very abstract! Can you provide some concrete codes?

Comment: do you have terminal access to the server the php code is running on?

Comment: Yes, actually I am running all on my own mac, and the php running host is localhost

Comment: if you look at the link, it gives concrete examples:

    chown -R youruser:www-data /folder/name